# How do I put 20MB of XML data into an SQL database?

Tags: sql, xml, parsing

I have a huge amount of XML. Many objects have subobjects, from which I want to generate tables and foreign keys. Nodes also have many attributes.

Is there a library out there (in php, python, or any convenient language) that can handle such a complicated file?

Comment: I don't know of any offhand. I know there are lot of products you can use to automatically do this out there on the market (search google for something like `automatic database converter xml to sql`). There might even be a good free one if you dig deep enough. But mainly what I want to say is that if you know any scripting languages, scripting up the conversion yourself is not very difficult and will probably not be much slower than learning how to use a new piece of software (and possibly purchasing it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you doing this?

There's a famous remark, from Michael Stonebraker I believe, that this is like taking your car to bits and placing each component on a separate shelf in your garage every time you come home from work in the evening. It's a lot of work, and it's usually quite unnecessary. Just store the XML in an XML database.

Comment: Thanks. What's a good XML database? I'm looking into http://xml.apache.org/xindice/